# Can I load a python code in python and parse it as normal code lines?

Tags: python, parsing, configuration, header, constants

I would like to be able to separate some defines meant for configuration, from the script where I would like to use them.
Ex:

```
## Config ##
antPatHeader = {

    # Name
    "name": "Antenna_Pattern_Tables",

    # Version
    "major_version": 0,
    "minor_version": 0,

}
```

Is there a streightforward way, like opening and reading files like

```
f = open(configFile, "r")  
f.read()  
f.close()
```

and then parsing them in the programm.

What is the best way to separate code like one would do for constants from the executing script?

Comment: Why can't you just `import config.py`?

Comment: I am afraid it is that straightforward. It says that the variables are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your configuration in a different file and load it as parameters in your script, the easiest way to do it would be to store it a markup language file such as

- [xml](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/)
- [yaml](http://yaml.org/)
- [json](https://www.json.org/)

Your config is already (almost) of a json form, so you can do the following:

**config.json:**

```
{
    "name": "Antenna_Pattern_Tables",
    "major_version": 0,
    "minor_version": 0,
}
```

Then in python:

```
import json

with open('config.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data["name"]) #"Antenna_Pattern_Tables"
print(data["major_version"]) #0
```

If you just want to use python variables from another file you can do:

**p2.py:**

```
test = 5
```

**p1.py**

```
import p2

print(p2.test) #5
```

Comment: That is a good idea. I used a dictionary here.. I also have a List defined that contains values of the keys in the dictionary, I mignt have a simple variabe and so on... I thought there is something like one in C can use a header file.

Comment: See update, it should accomplish everything you want to do

Comment: Is there a way just to call the whole code snippet at once?

Comment: You could try wrapping everything in your other python function in a function then calling that function ( p2.wholeFileFunction() )